# Do Assemblies have to be physical files? - WepAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly

We have an MVC UI that will generically draw itself based on data types it gets from the WebAPI.  On App start of the ui I call into my WebApi to pull the "LeadTypes" down in a list of Assemblies List using binary formatter to serialize and deserialize.  Problem is, when the references are removed from the UI, the deserializer blows up saying it cannot find InstallmentLoan, version 1.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies.  Well there are no dependencies other than system, these are just basic models with custom data annotations, etc.  The goal is to not have any of our types referenced on the UI.

Error "Could not load file or assembly 'LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

There has to be a clever way to use and reference in memory assemblies without having the physical file.  What I don't understand is why is it looking for a file if I have it in memory?

Any pointers would be great!

Here is the FusionLog:

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/MainTrunk2/LeadGenFramework-Copy/trunk/LeadGenFramwork.Web.Api.RestClient.Test/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : (Unknown)

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\charbaugh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8271.tmp
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MainTrunk2/LeadGenFramework-Copy/trunk/LeadGenFramwork.Web.Api.RestClient.Test/bin/Debug/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MainTrunk2/LeadGenFramework-Copy/trunk/LeadGenFramwork.Web.Api.RestClient.Test/bin/Debug/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MainTrunk2/LeadGenFramework-Copy/trunk/LeadGenFramwork.Web.Api.RestClient.Test/bin/Debug/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///E:/MainTrunk2/LeadGenFramework-Copy/trunk/LeadGenFramwork.Web.Api.RestClient.Test/bin/Debug/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan/LeadGenFramework.Entity.LeadType.InstallmentLoan.EXE.

Comment: How do you have it in memory?

Comment: just using a basic stream that is returned from the Web API get.

Comment: Binary serialization does not include any assemblies in its output, just their full names. If you want to deserialize the output, you either need to have the assemblies where they can be loaded or you need to use fancy deserialization techniques (surrogates etc.) to deserialize into objects of different types.

Comment: Anton, this is the route I'm going with.  I found that the assembly class only holds basic properties and not the actual data within the assembly files, method, properties and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  I was using reflections to get the assembly and then serializing the Assembly type.  Assembly only provides property information for the physical file assembly and it does not contain an entire graph of the file.  **I hope this helps someone, lesson learned!**

So I just used this on the controller and then the revers on the client.

```
    public MemoryStream Get()
    {
        List<MemoryStream> leadTypeAssemblyStreams = new List<MemoryStream>();

        foreach (string dllAssembly in _leadTypeNamespaces)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                string filename = dllAssembly;

                if (!filename.Contains(".dll"))
                    filename = filename + ".dll";

                using (FileStream file = new FileStream(AssemblyDirectory + "\\" + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                    file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
                    file.Close();

                    leadTypeAssemblyStreams.Add(ms);
                    ms.Close();
                }
            }    
        }

        return new MemoryStream(SerializeObj(leadTypeAssemblyStreams));
    }

    internal static string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }


    internal static byte[] SerializeObj(object obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);

            byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
            stream.Close();

            return bytes;
        }
    }
```

Now, I can just call the GetDeserializedFileStreamPaths(stream) and it will return a physical path to the files that were streamed from the WebApi.  Here is my WebApiClient class the UI will reference.

```
public class LFGWebApiClientHelpers
{
    public List<Type> GetLeadTypes(Stream stream)
    {
        List<string> assembliesFilePath = GetDeserializedFileStreamPaths(stream);
        List<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (string filePath in assembliesFilePath)
        {
            assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(filePath));
        }

        List<Type> leadTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Assembly asm in assemblies)
        {
            Type leadType = asm.GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebApiExportedTypeAttribute), false).Length > 0).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Lead"));
            leadTypes.Add(leadType);
        }

        return leadTypes;
    }

    private static List<string> GetDeserializedFileStreamPaths(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> assembliesPath = new List<string>();
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            List<MemoryStream> leadTypeAssemblyStreams = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<MemoryStream>;

            int fileNumber = 1;

            string leadTypeAsseblyDirectory = AssemblyDirectory.Replace("bin", "DownloadedLeadTypeAssemblies");

            if (!Directory.Exists(leadTypeAsseblyDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(leadTypeAsseblyDirectory);
            try
            {
                if (leadTypeAssemblyStreams == null)
                    throw new Exception("Lead type assembly stream cannot be null.");

                    foreach (MemoryStream leadTypeAssemblyStream in leadTypeAssemblyStreams)
                    {
                        string localFileLocation = leadTypeAsseblyDirectory +
                                                   string.Format("\\LeadType{0}.dll", fileNumber);

                        //add path for return type
                        assembliesPath.Add(localFileLocation);
                        using (
                            FileStream file = new FileStream(localFileLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            leadTypeAssemblyStream.WriteTo(file);
                            leadTypeAssemblyStream.Close();
                        }

                        fileNumber++;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new LGFException().SetMessage(ex);
            }

            stream.Close();

            return assembliesPath;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new LGFException().SetMessage(ex, "There was a problems during the deserializtion of LeadTypes.");
        }
    }

    private static string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the assemblies from somewhere, for that you will need to stream the assembly content and call assembly.load(byte[] rawAssembly).

Comment: Yes, I cannot get it to work.  But could also be that I'm not serializing correctly on the webapi side.

Comment: So trying to understand again - Are you attempting to serialize your actual POCO types assembly over the wire to the client? Sounds like a security hole waiting to be exploited.

Figure out what metadata you want to pass to the client for describing your types and pass only that, then constructor what you need on the client. Beyond security, passing assemblies around leads to many things that can go wrong (1. Dependencies missing, 2. Only C# clients, 3. Framework compatibility issues)

Comment: Yes, the poco.  I would have the concern you mentioned but this a private webapi.  Knowing what I do now, I would have just serialized the types....but also need access to Custom attributes, data annotations, etc.  Thanks.